# Trim strings in Laravel automatically

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream

Is there a way to trim all data that goes in the database? I thought there was a trim middleware that would do this, but it’s still possible to save data to the database with spaces before and after strings. I use Jetstream and Livewire if that matters.

Comment: There is a [middleware](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/app/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php) that already trims input. What is the input you have that is not being trimmed ?

Comment: I have a form, I type ” a ” and that is what is being saved to the database, not ”a”.

Comment: You could use a setter that will trim your value every time you set it. These are called mutators: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator

Comment: Yes, but would be great if I could get this global trimmer to work. Any thoughts?

Comment: You can use TrimStrings and ConvertEmptyStringsToNull

Comment: @dev They're in my Kernel `protected $middleware` file, but still not trimming. Ideas?

Comment: Not sure why I got downvoted, but seems like it's Livewire that turns it off. https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/823

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `TrimStrings Middleware`.

**References**

[1]. https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-middleware

[2]. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#input-trimming-and-normalization

Comment: Thanks. They're in my Kernel file's `protected $middleware` but still not trimming. Ideas? Do I need to activate it or something?

Comment: Seems like it's Livewire that turns it off. https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/823